# Play FLAC via DirectShow

Tags: c++, media-player, directshow, flac

I would like write an simple (only one exe) music player.
The player is work if I want play mp3, but didn't work if I want use MadFLAC Filter.
I can't connect of the MadFLAC pins. Always drop 0x80040207 error.
(I think, the MadFLAC filter is loaded correctly, I can add to the GraphBuilder without error and see in the EnumFilters.)

I do not insist on using MadFLAC. All other options is interest me with which I can play a FLAC file via DirectShow without install codec pack to client pc.

Here is my simplified code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <strmif.h>
#include <control.h>
#include <uuids.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "strmiids.lib")

IPin* GetPin(IBaseFilter *bFilter, PIN_DIRECTION pindir)
{
    IEnumPins *EnumPin;
    bFilter->EnumPins(&EnumPin);
    unsigned long int num;
    IPin *TempPin = NULL;
    do {
        EnumPin->Next(1, &TempPin, &num);
        if (num != 0)
        {
            PIN_INFO PinInfo;
            TempPin->QueryPinInfo(&PinInfo);
            if (PinInfo.dir == pindir) break;
        }
    } while (num != 0);
    return TempPin;
}

typedef HRESULT __stdcall DLLGETCLASSOBJECT(REFCLSID rclsid, REFIID riid, void **ppv);
HRESULT CreateFilterFromFile(HINSTANCE hLibInst, GUID TGUID, void **Filter) {
    IClassFactory * ClassFactory;
    HRESULT Result = S_FALSE;
    FARPROC func;
    func = GetProcAddress(hLibInst, "DllGetClassObject");
    if (func != NULL)
    {
        IClassFactory *classFactory;
        DLLGETCLASSOBJECT *dllGetClassObject = (DLLGETCLASSOBJECT*)func;
        Result = dllGetClassObject(TGUID, IID_IClassFactory, (void**)&classFactory);
        if (SUCCEEDED(Result))
        {
            Result = classFactory->CreateInstance(NULL, IID_IBaseFilter, Filter);
            classFactory->Release();
        }
    }
    return Result;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

void Player(bool isFlac) {
    IGraphBuilder * player;
    IMediaControl * mcontrol;
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IGraphBuilder, (void **)&player);
    player->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void **)&mcontrol);
    IBaseFilter *ARS = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AsyncReader, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter, (void **)&ARS);
    IBaseFilter * AudioDecoderFilter = NULL;
    if (isFlac) {
        hr = player->AddSourceFilter(L"D:\\test.flac", L"Async Reader Source", &ARS);
        GUID CLSID_MadFlacAudioDecoder;
        CLSIDFromString(L"{6B257121-CBB6-46B3-ABFA-B14DFA98C4A6}", &CLSID_MadFlacAudioDecoder);
        HINSTANCE FHMPCAudioFilterInst = CoLoadLibrary(L"d:\\_MadFlac\\madFlac.ax", true);
        if (FHMPCAudioFilterInst != 0) {
            hr = CreateFilterFromFile(FHMPCAudioFilterInst, CLSID_MadFlacAudioDecoder, (void **)&AudioDecoderFilter);
            if (AudioDecoderFilter != NULL) {
                player->AddFilter(AudioDecoderFilter, L"MadFLAC Audio decoder (internal)");
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        hr = player->AddSourceFilter(L"D:\\test.mp3", L"Async Reader Source", &ARS);
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MPEG1Splitter, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter, (void **)&AudioDecoderFilter);
        hr = player->AddFilter(AudioDecoderFilter, L"MPEG1Splitter");
    }

    IBaseFilter *PCM = NULL;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ACMWrapper, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter, (void **)&PCM);
    hr = player->AddFilter(PCM, L"PCM");

    IBaseFilter *DSE = NULL;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_DSoundRender, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter, (void **)&DSE);
    hr = player->AddFilter(DSE, L"Direct Renderer");

    //ARS -> AdioDecoder
    hr = GetPin(ARS, PINDIR_OUTPUT)->Connect(GetPin(AudioDecoderFilter, PINDIR_INPUT), NULL);
    //If I use MadFLAC filter this hresult is 0x80040207 
    if (FAILED(hr)) MessageBoxA(NULL, "There is no common media type between these pins.", "Error", NULL);
    //AudioDecoderFilter -> PCM
    hr = GetPin(AudioDecoderFilter, PINDIR_OUTPUT)->Connect(GetPin(PCM, PINDIR_INPUT), NULL);
    //PCM -> DSE
    hr = GetPin(PCM, PINDIR_OUTPUT)->Connect(GetPin(DSE, PINDIR_INPUT), NULL);
    //ListGraph(player);
    mcontrol->Run();
}


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = "Teszt";
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) { MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK); return 0; }
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "Teszt", "AppName", WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 460, 240, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if (hwnd == NULL) { MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK); return 0; }
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    Player(false);

    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

**I use VS2015, native C++.**

I would have tried to use LibFLAC as well, but I was already stuck there that I couldn’t Build because it threw hundreds of bugs, which I eventually reduced to less than 20 but I had already given up there after several hours of suffering.

https://github.com/xiph/flac

https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/xiph/releases/oggdsf/

Comment: Why not use WASAPI which is the recommended way to playback audio by microsoft?

Comment: Also, why not just grab RAW samples from the file and write a simple custom tranform routine?

Comment: Directshow is outdated is this the reason why you are using VisualStudio 2015.

Comment: Usually I write my applications to run from XP to Win10. As far as I know Wasapi came in with Vista. That’s why I want to solve it using Directshow. 
How can I grab RAW samples from FLAC? "simple custom tranform routine" can you link to example, to see what this looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Windows is not shipped with FLAC decoder for DirectShow. Hence, ability to play FLAC audio via DirectShow requires a third party decoder. If you don't want to reply on a codec pack, you need to either bundle certain FLAC decoder with DirectShow interface or implement a decoder in code. https://xiph.org/dshow looks like the best third party decoder option to me, implementing a DirectShow filter over FLAC library requires some development effort, which is probably an overkill for the task in question.

Comment: You didn't write anything new. I know the codec you recommend. If you have read through my question, I have also linked the codec you mentioned at the bottom and described it why I can't use it.

Comment: The point is that you will have to choose among options you think you cannot use. There is also another one: Windows has FLAC decoder in the form of Media Foundation Transform, you can develop a DirectShow wrapper over it and have decoding enabled this way. It it unlikely that you would go this way because it looks more complicated than linking libflac which you  already have issues with.

Comment: Thanks for detailing what I can't do, but I know these and won't help to me to solve the problem. Yes, I can't use these libraries, that's why I opened this question post.